# Symfony2 Embedded Forms

Tags: forms, symfony

I am trying to understand the embeded forms in symfony2.

I have two entities `icon` and `asset` There is a many to many relationship between them as well as a `OneToOne` on `$icon->imageLarge` and `icon->imageThumb`.

note: (Asset is the class name but referenced as `$image...` inside the icon)

What I am trying to end up with is a gallery of images related to an icon and two columns on the icon to reflect which image is the main thumbnail and the main large image...

I have created an IconType:

```
class IconType extends AbstractType{

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
    $builder->add('name');
    $builder->add('imageThumb', new AssetType());
    $builder->add('imageLarge', new AssetType());
}

public function getName(){
    return 'icon';
}


public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver){
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'SixString\PearBundle\Entity\Icon',
    ));
}
}
```

and an AssetType:

```
class AssetType extends AbstractType{

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
    $builder->add('file');
}

public function getName(){
    return 'asset';
}


public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver){
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'SixString\PearBundle\Entity\Asset',
        ));
}
}
```

I create my form in my controller:

```
$icon = new Icon;
$form = $this->createForm(new IconType(), $icon);

if($request->isMethod('POST')) {
    $form->bind($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
      ....
    }
}
return $this->render('SixStringPearBundle:Icon:form.html.twig', array("form" => $form->createView()));
```

Everything appears to be interacting so far, I have created my form in my template and it shows the icon name field as well as the two asset file uploaders.

Where I am getting lost is how to access the uploaded `assets`. I need to persist these two `assets` to db and then set `$icon->addImage($asset1); $icon->addImage($asset2);` for the many to many and also `$icon->setImageThumb($asset1); $icon->setImageLarge($asset2);`

I'm not sure if this all makes sense, but any help figuring out the logic or simply how to access these assets would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the uploaded assets as follows:

```
$imageThumbFile = $form->get('imageThumb')->get('file')->getData();
$imageLargeFile = $form->get('imageLarge')->get('file')->getData();
```

If you are planning to store these in the DB as blobs then you may find this SO question helpful: [How do I persist Images with Doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966940/how-do-i-persist-images-with-doctrine)

Alternatively, you can store uploaded files in the file system and integrate the file upload into your entity lifecycle by following the cookbook entry [How to handle File Uploads with Doctrine](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html)

EDIT:

If using  the lifecycle callbacks approach from the cookbook entry:

1. Implement Asset class similarly to Document in the example
2. Modify Icon class to call $this->addImage($asset) from both Icon::setImageThumb() and Icon::setImageLarge()
3. For Icon class add cascade persist to the $images relationship
4. From the controller call persist only on $icon and everything else should take care of itself.

Comment: I am pretty much implementing the How to handle File Uploads with Doctrine article and simply storing the path. I am using the lifecycle callbacks. Because I'm using this method of uploading, When I call: `$imageThumbFile = $form->get('imageThumb')->get('file')->getData();` can I then call `em->persist($imageThumb); $icon->setImageThumb($imageThumb);`

Comment: Edited to answer your question.

Comment: Sorry I have been away for a bit and just getting back to this. I have not tested this yet but understand most of the principals you described. If this works it will most likely solve my problem. I am still confused how I would access the objects inside the controller before actually persisting the `icon`. I may not need to access them in this example but I am just trying to further understand how this all works. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to check if the image is already persisted/flushed before calling `$icon->addImage($asset)` in the `Icon::setImage...` functions? I may need to set the image using an already existing asset