# Symfony 2: Display an image mediumblob

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to display a MEDIUMBLOB field of my database, which contain images, with Symfony 2 but I can't do it...

To do this, I created my own Doctrine type. Here is the code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Personal type to support MediumBlob
 *
 * @author Leglopin
 */
namespace MC\UserBundle\Doctrine\Types;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;
use Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;

/**
 * Type that maps a PHP object to a mediumblob SQL type.
 */
class MediumBlobType extends Type
{
    const MEDIUMBLOB = 'mediumblob';

    public function getName()
    {
        return self::MEDIUMBLOB;
    }

    public function getSQLDeclaration(array $fieldDeclaration, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return $platform->getDoctrineTypeMapping('MEDIUMBLOB');
    }

    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return ($value === null) ? null : base64_encode($value);
    }

    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return ($value === null) ? null : base64_decode($value);
    }
}
```

Then, to display the image I'm doing this:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{ photo }}">
```

where the photo variable is defined in my controller like this:

```
$photo = base64_encode($user->getPhoto());
```

But nothing is displayed

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Do you added the type? Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738767/how-add-blob-type-in-doctrine-2-using-symfony-2)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I added my type like that in my controller file:

```
public function boot()
{
    $em = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager');

    Type::addType('mediumblob', 'MC\UserBundle\Doctrine\Types\MediumBlobType');

    $em->getConnection()->getDatabasePlatform()
       ->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('MEDIUMBLOB', 'mediumblob');
}
```

Comment: The question and answer helped me implement MEDIUM blob in Laravel! Thanks!
this Medium article too: https://medium.com/@matriphe/adding-custom-char-type-in-laravel-migration-780d8a9cac29